# SocketException on remote server

Tags: java, network-programming

I have a problem when trying to connect to a remote server.

```
SocketException: Invalid argument or cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
```

Here is how i create the socket

```
if (socket == null) {
        socket = new Socket();

    try {
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
    }
    }
    dstAddress = new InetSocketAddress(server, dstPort); 
    srcAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", srcPort);
    socket.bind(srcAddress);
    socket.connect(dstAddress);
```

Everything works fine on localhost.

Comment: What's the value of `dstPort`?

Answer (score 1):

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.finance.moneydance.general/5389

> This sometimes occurs on other platforms - it used to occasionally 
>       occur on earlier versions of Mac OS X.  The solution definitely lies 
>       outside of Moneydance since MD is requesting (through Java) to open a 
>       standard network connection and the system is saying that it is     unable to do so.
>
> The only solution I have found for this is to reboot your computer.
>       If you are also running other software that uses a lot of network 
>       resources, try not running that for a while to see if it makes a
>       difference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bind() call. It is not required.

Comment: It is not required, but i need it to specify the port on the client machine.  But it works on remote server if i remove it effectively.  It is the bind that causes the exception.  Why ?  How can i do it with the bind call ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running your program with

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

when connecting to the remote system.